# Post Request getting failed due to webkitformboundary in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

We have a recorded script using Blaze Meter(HTTPS call) and run in JMeter, One POST request getting failed and shows ***"500 Internal Server error"***. In Post request, JSON passed in form of ***"form-Data"*** as parameter. When endpoint executed we observed Webkitformbounday in HTTP header, Please give some solution for

1. HTTPs Request
2. HTTP Header Manager
3. POST Request Body
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZehU.png)

Comment: Dear @Ankit, can you add more info, like the script you are using? By a better description of your problem, you increase the rate of receiving good solutions.

Comment: When we record script using JMETER from IP based URL (HTTP calls) then Post request executed successfully, and in Header content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary(.......) is not present. it is displaying only with HTTPs calls.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the recording solution you're using isn't very suitable for building proper [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request, I would suggest the following amendments:

1. Untick `Use multipart/form-data` box in the HTTP Request sampler
2. Remove `issueDetail` parameter name and put it to the end of "path"
3. Change [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header value to `application/json`
4. `Authorization` header value might need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) if the token life span is short

   [image]

More information: [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
As per your suggestion, we have changed content type as application/JSON, Untick use multipart/form-data. 
when we Remove issueDetail parameter name and put it to the end of "path" , it is showing 404 not found error because of server path is not found for endpoints.